# Post answer from HTML to php to sit in a while loop

Tags: php

I have a HTML page with multiple choice questions with a form set to POST. When submit is clicked it runs the php page.  the php page connects to my database with the correct answers etc... I need to get the users answers from the HTML page into my php page but as it is in a loop it can't just keep selecting the first question answer selected. Is this possible at all?  I've looked or 3 days and no joy, which is a shame as the rest of my script works fine.  Any guidance would be great. Thank you

```
$x = 0;
$score = 0;  

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){

        echo "Question Number: " . $row['Questionid'] . '<br />';
        echo "Question: " . $row['Questiontext'] . '<br />';
        echo "Correct Answer: " . $row['Correctanswer'] . '<br />';
/** I want to POST the answer from the HTML form and call it    $value.  
My problem...no idea how to do this.  As it is in a loop each time it comes 
to this line it needs to also move down the HTML page i.e. to the second 
question etc...`*/


      echo "Your Answer: " . $value."\n" . '<br />';
        echo "<br>";

        $correct = $row['Correctanswer'] ;

        if ($value == $correct ) {
            $score++;
```

HTML

```
   <select name="answer1"> 
                    <option>Tu </option>
                    <option>El</option>
                    <option>Yo</option>
                    <option>Ellos</option>
                    <option selected="selected"> </option>
                  </select>
                hablo </div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td height="54"><div align="left" class="style15">2 - You drink </div></td>
              <td><div align="left" class="style13">
                  <select name="answer2">
                    <option>Nosotros</option>
                    <option>Tu</option>
                    <option>Vosotros</option>
                    <option>Yo</option>
                    <option selected="selected"> </option>
                  </select>
```

Comment: Post your HTML code. Unless we know how your HTML form is setup, it is hard to give a correct answer. For instance, where do you get `$value` set up? You might need to have a loop inside the loop if your HTML form contains multiple questions, etc...

Comment: Hi,  I've posted the HTML, thanks for looking

Comment: Caanot see your HTML, but I have answered assuming the answers in your HTML form is input type text. See below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume your answer input field in your HTML is `<INPUT type='text' name='answer1'>` where 1 is the question id in your database. Your PHP should be something like the following:

```
$x = 0;
$score = 0;  

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){

        echo "Question Number: " . $row['Questionid'] . '<br />';
        echo "Question: " . $row['Questiontext'] . '<br />';
        echo "Correct Answer: " . $row['Correctanswer'] . '<br />';

        $value = htmlspecialchars ($_POST['answer' . $row['Questionid']]); 
        echo "Your Answer: " . $value."\n" . '<br />';
        echo "<br>";

        $correct = $row['Correctanswer'] ;

        if ($value == $correct ) {
            $score++;
}
```

Comment: Hameed thank you for your time I do very much appreciate your help.  I'v posted the HTML in my question above.  Hopefully this time it will show.  Otherwise I have updated the questions as follows:  <select name="answer1"> and then <select name="answer2"> for the next question etc...  The question id's in the database are 1,2,3 etc...  I have updated the php code and ran it in my browser.  I recieve the following error       Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$row' (T_VARIABLE), expecting ']' in C:\xampp\htdocs\SSF\1B results.php on line 34

Comment: and the line it refers to is the one you suggested  $value = htmlspecialchars ($_POST['answer' . $row['Questionid']]);

Comment: Glad to be of assistence. tc.

Answer (score 1):

You can set your form input element NAMEs to something that includes the Questionid, eg
<input name=ans1>
and refer to them dynamically in php.  in your PHP it is expecting the user answer to be stored in  $value, you can do things like this to retrieve the POST data dynamically:

```
$value=$_POST['ans'.$row['Questionid']];
```

That finds the form's related answer based on the questionid in your database

Comment: Hi,  thank you or the response.  It seems that you have identified what I am after.  I'm quite new to php so could you kindly expand. DO i go into my html form and add <input id="the reference to my database answer 1">.  If so where in the script would I put this.

Comment: You cannot retrive the input's ID through $_POST. You need the name attribute `<input name=ans1>`

Comment: Correct, but for readability assuming numerical database IDs, in your HTML form make all the input NAMEs be some text + the db reference to that particular answer.  e.g. answer id in the DB is 567 so the input's NAME would be something like "Input567".  In the PHP code you recall as $value=$_POST['Input'.$row['Questionid']]; exactly where you noted it in your question

Answer (score 1):

You have to get the input on the html page by name. i.e.    then on your backend php retrieve the value of input1:
$input1 = $_POST['input1'];

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I've already done this and the problem is because it is in a while loop it will keep getting "input1" whereas I want it to go and get "input2",3,4,5 etc...

Answer (score 1):

Where Do you set the `$value` variable? You haven't show any of your HTML so I am assuming u have long form with a lot of question. Try making an array of the answers and have something like that:

```
$corectAnswers=null;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $corectAnswers[]=$row;
}
```

Then for each answer use check if it is correct:

```
foreach ($corectAnswers as $key => $value) {
    if($value==$userAnswers[$key]){
    $answers[]['isCorrent']=true;
    $score++;
    //do some html stuff here or after the end of foreach loop
    }else{
        $answers[]['isCorrent']=false;
        //again html
    }

}
```